# How do I add a certain amount of attempts to my code after asking a question?

Tags: python

I have a code to pick a random song with the artist but only the first letters are shown and the user has to guess the song name by the given artist, I need to add 2 attempts where if they get it wrong I end the code but if they get it right they move on to the next question.

```
f1 = open("Eminem.txt", "r")            #Opens external notepad file and the read mode ("r")
f2 = open("UnlikePluto.txt", "r")        #Opens external notepad file and the read mode ("r")
f3 = open("Marshmello.txt", "r")        #Opens external notepad file and the read mode ("r")
f4 = open("Eminem1.txt", "r")            #Opens external notepad file and the read mode ("r")
f5 = open("UnlikePluto1.txt", "r")        #Opens external notepad file and the read mode ("r")
f6 = open("Marshmello1.txt", "r")        #Opens external notepad file and the read mode ("r")
f7 = open("Eminem2.txt", "r")            #Opens external notepad file and the read mode ("r")
f8 = open("UnlikePluto2.txt", "r")        #Opens external notepad file and the read mode ("r")
f9 = open("Marshmello2.txt", "r")        #Opens external notepad file and the read mode ("r")
```

I have got the artist names, song names and actual question saved in an external file but I dont know how to code the question with 2 attempts to guess the song. Thanks :D

Comment: See if my answer makes sense to you @Max_Anzelloti I have tried to cover your choosing for 2 attempts, as well as moving to next song of next artist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a variable to count the number of tries. and add it to a while loop. something like this:

```
count = 0
while count<2:
    answer = input('enter the song name: ')
    if answer == solution:
        <move on to next question>
    else:
        count +=1
```

Comment: fix indentation of `else` statement

Comment: You can improve this answer by : 1) making the program print something like 'good answer' / 'wrong answer' 2) Specify how it is supposed to move on to next question, should the if block be left empty and why ? 3) Generalizing the answer so OP can sweep the entire set of questions

Answer (score 0):

I have written a standalone code, where if the artist is known, and the song chosen is known, will work with 3 attempts, and will display the right or wrong answer accordingly. You can extend it according to your needs!

```py
def choose_song(artist, songs, song_choosen):

    idx = 0
    guess_correct = False
    song = ''

    while idx < 3:

        guess = input('The artists is {} and the song is {}. Enter your guess {}>>'.format(artist, song_choosen[:3], idx+1))

        #Iterate through all songs to check if the guess is right, if it is, break out of for loop
        for song in songs:
            if guess.lower().strip() == song.lower().strip():
                guess_correct = True
                song = guess
                break
        #If the user guessed correctly, we are done else try again
        if guess_correct:
            break
        else:
            idx+= 1

    #Show the final output accordingly
    if guess_correct:
        print('You guessed correctly. The song is indeed {}'.format(song))
    else:
        print('You guessed wrong. The song is {}'.format(song_choosen))


choose_song('Eminem', ['Rap God', 'Slim Shady'], 'Rap God')
```

The output will be

```
The artists is Eminem and the song is Rap. Enter your guess 1>>Rap King
The artists is Eminem and the song is Rap. Enter your guess 2>>Rap Dog
The artists is Eminem and the song is Rap. Enter your guess 3>>Rap Kid
You guessed wrong. The song is Rap God

The artists is Eminem and the song is Rap. Enter your guess 1>>Rap God
You guessed correctly. The song is indeed Rap God

The artists is Eminem and the song is Rap. Enter your guess 1>>Rap Dog
The artists is Eminem and the song is Rap. Enter your guess 2>>rap god
You guessed correctly. The song is indeed rap god
```

To build on top of this, you can just do this.

```
import random

#Your dictionary of artists to songs list
dct = {'Eminem': ['Rap God', 'Slim Shady'],
       'Marshmello': ['Happier', 'Friends'],
       'Pearl Jam': ['Even Flow', 'Black']}

import random
#Iterate through all artists and pick a song at random
for key, value in dct.items():
    choose_song(key, value, random.choice(value))
```

The output might look like.

```
The artists is Eminem and the song is Rap. Enter your guess 1>>rap god
You guessed correctly. The song is indeed rap god
The artists is Marshmello and the song is Hap. Enter your guess 1>>Happier
You guessed correctly. The song is indeed Happier
The artists is Pearl Jam and the song is Bla. Enter your guess 1>>Black
You guessed correctly. The song is indeed Black
```